# Microsoft Power Automate - issues with elements and windows (Desktop recorder)

Tags: windows, automation, power-automate, recorder

I have a very general question. I have the desktop version of Microsoft power automate on my machine (Win 10). I am currently trying to record various flows through the Desktop recorder to be reused later on for automation of processes.

But most of the time there will be a step in the flow where the application wont be able to manage the automation, like when sometimes some elements or windows cant be found.

Have you encountered any of these issues and have you managed to come across solutions to come over it?